# RSpec request logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rack

I'm using **Rails 5.1** with **RSpec 3.6**. While running request specs of my API endpoints I can see the requested endpoints in output, for example:

```
[2017-09-07 17:39:03 +0200] INFO -- 200 -- db=1.27 total=10.16 view=8.89 -- GET /api/v1/users host=www.example.com params={}
```

Here it is a spec:

```
subject { get "/api/v1/users", headers: headers, params: {} }

it "renders users with 200 status" do
  subject
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
end
```

Is it possible to disable them somehow? I've noticed it comes from `ActionPack` and it appears when executing [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L263).

Comment: What is your spec code doing? (Show us the code!) And what do you mean by "output" -- to STDOUT, or to a log file?

Comment: I've added an example of my spec that just makes an API call. By output I meant to STDOUT which is displayed in the terminal while running specs.

Comment: Have you got an answer to this? Having the same problem.

Comment: @redFur check out your core/base class of Grape, there should be a line responsible for logging like `use GrapeLogging::Middleware::RequestLogger`